# How do I export from Blender into Unity with textures?

Tags: unity, blender

I have a Blender model, it has a texture on it created with "Images as Planes" addon.

If I open the shading tab I can see the texture and material are there.

When I save the Blender model in the Assets folder of Unity, I don't see that it created a separate materials file with it, not sure if it is saved internally.

I know in order to import a model with textures I need to create a Textures and Materials folders in Unity.

So I added the two folders and placed the Texture used for Images as Planes into the Textures folder.

However, Unity only imported the model, there is no texture on it.

What do I need to do for Unity to import both the model and texture?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this was to go to `File → External → Data → Pack Resources`

Then `File → External → Data → Unpack Resources`

Choose `Write/Overwrite current`

This created the texture folder and imported into Unity correctly.